# How to place DIV elements with images next to each other

Tags: css

I have 5 images that I want to put next to each other, these images is going to become a slider that's going to slide left or right. No matter what I try nothing seems to make it go next to each other. I have tried float:left, position:absolute, display: inline.

here is my html

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
                <div class="slider">
                    <div class="portfolio-overlay">

                            <div id="portfolio_0" class="portfolio-active portfolio-single"><img src="images/image1.jpg"></div>
                            <div id="portfolio_1" class="portfolio-inactive portfolio-single"><img src="images/image2.jpg"></div>
                            <div id="portfolio_2" class="portfolio-inactive portfolio-single"><img src="images/image3.jpg"></div>
                            <div id="portfolio_3" class="portfolio-inactive portfolio-single"><img src="images/image4.jpg"></div>
                            <div id="portfolio_4" class="portfolio-inactive portfolio-single"><img src="images/image5.jpg"></div>
                            <div id="portfolio_5" class="portfolio-inactive portfolio-single"><img src="images/image6.jpg"></div>

                    </div>   
                </div>
```

and this is my css

```
.slider-wrapper {
padding: 25px 0 0;
}

.portfolio-single {
float: left;
width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: 70% is a bit too much... or? you want it really 70% and than every next to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DEMO WITH ANIMATION](http://jsbin.com/dukib/4/edit)

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dukib/3/edit)

```
.slider-wrapper {
  overflow:hidden; /* to remove page scrollbars */
  padding: 25px 0 0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:0; /* to remove ~4px whitespace */
}

.portfolio-single {
  /*reset fontsize if needed*/
  display:inline-block;
  width:70%;
}
.portfolio-single img{
  vertical-align:top;
  width:100%;
}
```

Without using `align-left` we can use on a parent element `white-space` as `nowrap`, this will make sure to prevent wrap on inner `inline` or **`inline-block`** elements.

As said above we than need to respectively set the slides to `inline-block`.

using inline-block on elements they'll be in an inline flow, which means that if in your HTML you have every slide in a new line, a `4px` (it's a *whitespace!*) gap will appear next to each slide.

to remove it use on the parent element `font-size:0;`

If you plan to have text inside your slides than you'll need to set `font-size:16px` back to your children slides.

`vertical-align:top` or any other align value makes sure to place your images at the right *vertical* place inside their parent containers.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you gave each image a width of 70%. So each image was taking up a new line.
If you have 5 images, then the max width to have them all on the same line would be 20%. But with any padding/border/margin will add to that, so you might need to put under 20%.

http://jsfiddle.net/rNa9v/1/

```
.portfolio-single {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;  /* changed to 10% instead of 70% */
}
```

Comment: thanks that helped a bit but now the images are on top of each other instead of sitting next to each other

Answer (score 0):

Your img are in divs so they each take the full width of the page.
You can change this behavior by making the divs "inline":

```
.portfolio-single {display: inline-block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9377D/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
.portfolio-single {
    float: left;
    width: 16%;     /* 100/6 */
}
```

You can calculate it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can change the div option.It could solve the problem.

for further assistance follow the link..    : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp